# Jmeter parameter names and values from csv

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way I could assign parameter names and values both to a request from a csv file.
E.g.
In a certain recording, there are five check boxes.
When I click all of them and submit the form, the form data that gets recorded is:
geo=1
geo=2
geo=3
geo=4
geo=5

Now, when I select only 2 check boxes the form data is:
geo=1
geo=2

The other parameters are not sent with the request.
How can I emulate this in Jmeter.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: create a csv with lines likes,
geo=1 geo=2 geo=3 geo=4 geo=5 \n
geo=1 geo=2 \n
geo=3 geo=4 geo=5 \n

(\n for seperate lines)

Comment: But how can they be assigned as parameter names ?

Comment: directly use/replace them in http request which you are sending

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to simply create 5 different parameters

`Param1: geo=1`
`Param2: geo=1 geo=2`
`Param3: geo=1 geo=2 geo=3`

etc.

then you could create a random controller and put 5 different requests under it, all with a different parameter.

Hope this helps.